# Component is not rendering on React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I created a card component and on Click i would like to render some articles, i'm trying to use react but i don't know whats wrong with my code (I'm a beginner).

When i click the url is behaving as i want with the id of the article but the page is blank and nothing appear on the console (even my console.log)

```
class JobCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch(url)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(result =>
        this.setState({
          data: result,
          isLoading: false
        })
      );
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading === true) return <LoadingSpinner />;
    else {
      const { match } = this.props;
      return (
        <>
          <div>
            {data.map(job => (
              <div>
                <div key={job._id} className="blog-card">
                  <div className="meta"
                          <Link
                            to={{
                              pathname: `${match.url}/${job._id}/${
                                job.position_name
                              }`,
                              state: job
                            }}
                          >
                            {job.workplace_name}
                          </Link>{" "}
                          Job Restaurant
                        </span>
                      </p>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <Route path={`${match.path}/:id`} component={Articles} />
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
          )}
          <Footer />
        </>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default JobCard;
```

Articles Component that is not rendering:

```
import React from 'react'

const Articles = ({ location }) => (
    <div>
      <h1>{location.state.restaurant}</h1>
      <h2>{location.state.article}</h2>
      {location.state.position_name}
      <h4>Hello</h4>
    </div>
  )

  export default Articles;
```

Ant the App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import JobCard from "./components/Cards/JobCard";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div>
        hello World
      </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/JobCard">JobCard</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Route exact path="/JobCard" component={JobCard} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

export default App;
```

Comment: What are the errors logged in the browser console? Where is `url`variable referenced in `Job.componentWillMount` declared? Please edit your question to provide this information.

Comment: The url is referenced to a rest api that I made it’s just a JSON api! And I don’t get any error on the console, just when I access the component Articles on click I get the Id in the url as I want but the component is empty..

Comment: I try to reproduce this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-dynamic-routes?file=Topics.js

Comment: looks fine from that demo

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the Articles Route inside a data.map loop in your JobCard component. It should be outside the loop. This is causing problem in your case.

Comment: Even outside of the data.map the component article is not rendering